# The 'i2c_write_blocking' function in Pico SDK

Tags: pi-pico, c

I am confused... I'm using the `i2c_write_blocking` function, but getting a strange result:

If I do this - everything works as it should; i.e. I can read the values back from `CONFIG_REG`, and they match with the values I write below.

```
#define ADDR _u(0x40)
#define CONFIG_REG _u(0x00)
i2c_init(i2c_default, 100000);
uint8_t condata[3];
condata[0] = CONFIG_REG; 
condata[1] = 97
condata[2] = 37
i2c_write_blocking (i2c_default, ADDR, condata, 3, false);
```

But if I do this - things do **not** work as they should; the values I read back do **not** match with the values I write below.

```
#define ADDR _u(0x40)
#define CONFIG_REG _u(0x00)
i2c_init(i2c_default, 100000);
uint8_t reg = CONFIG_REG;  
uint8_t condt[2];
condt[0] = 97;
condt[1] = 37;
i2c_write_blocking (i2c_default, ADDR, &reg, 1, true);
i2c_write_blocking (i2c_default, ADDR, condt, 2, false);
```

And here's how I ***read*** the register:

```
#define ADDR _u(0x40)
#define CONFIG_REG _u(0x00)
i2c_init(i2c_default, 100000);
uint8_t reg = CONFIG_REG;  
uint8_t rcvdata[2];
i2c_write_blocking (i2c_default, ADDR, &reg, 1, true);
i2c_read_blocking (i2c_default, ADDR, rcvdata, 2, false);
```

I've checked the return values from the two `i2c_write_blocking` calls, and I get a `1` from the first, and a `2` from the second (i.e. what I should see for the commands above). I'm using a recently-installed SDK for the Pico, and running that on an RPi5.

Can someone explain what is happening?